# How to set "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" via Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-sql-database

In the Azure Portal on an SQL Server there is this network setting (highlighted in yellow):

[image]

How can I set this via Terraform? I could not find a matching option in the [mssql_server](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_server) docs.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8714) once.

Answer (score 1):

Please try by setting firewall rule with “0.0.0.0” as the allowed IP address and that should do the trick.

Comment: Well, that would be more than just Azure network, right?

Comment: Nope. It’s only for Azure services.

Answer (score 1):

use it like in Terraform

```
resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "appServiceIP" {
  name                = "appServiceIP"
  resource_group_name = local.resourceGroupName
  server_name         = local.sqlServerName
  start_ip_address    = "0.0.0.0"
  end_ip_address      = "0.0.0.0"

  depends_on          = [module.sqlserverdb]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For an Azure SQL database it's this

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule" "appServiceIP" {
  name                = "AllowAccessFromAzure"
  server_id           = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
  start_ip_address    = "0.0.0.0"
  end_ip_address      = "0.0.0.0"
}
```